# Django admin objects permissions

Tags: django, django-admin, django-guardian

I'm struggling at building a website with Django. On that website, I want to have a lot of information about TV shows. I want my user to be able to insert and modify information.  The information needs to be moderated, a change should not be published before being accepted by a moderator.

I came across [django-moderation](https://github.com/dominno/django-moderation) as a solution to that aspect.
My user will log into another instance of django-admin, with [different user rights](http://www.tryolabs.com/Blog/2012/06/18/django-administration-interface-non-staff-users/).
I'm adding [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) to deal with per-object permissions.

I'm lost a bit lost now.  I think I'll find how to interface all those things, and it will work in a few weeks after reading all the docs, making all the mistakes, etc...
I am wondering thou if the architecture makes sense, if are software components I am missing out on.

Thank you for your consideration.

edit : BTW, working with django 1.7 on python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

django-moderation looks interesting, I haven't used it.  There's not a lot of activity in the project, but it's active.  I think it will suit the use-case you have in mind.  I considered django-guardian recently for a project and rejected it in favour of extending tastypie's authorizations.  I think my use case was a bit different, I needed to maintain constraints on foreign key relationships that were hard to express with django-guardian.  If you only intend to allow or reject read/write permissions and don't need to validate anything beyond rudimentary data points, it will do a good job (in that case, use [Django's model validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)).

In general: Django has a wide assortment of [easily included apps](https://www.djangopackages.com/).  in general: if you can solve it with pip install, do so.

Comment: btw, i work on django 1.7 powered by python 3.4, and it seems like django-moderation isn't compatible.